# Prove: if |$z|=1$ then $|iz-\overline{z}|\leq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove: if |$z|=1$ then $|iz-\overline{z}|\leq 2$

$$|iz-\overline{z}|=|i(a+bi)-(a-bi)|=|-(a+b)+(a+b)i|=\sqrt{(a+b)^2+(a+b)^2}=\sqrt{2(a+b)^2}$$

On the other hand $|z|=1\iff \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1\iff a^2+b^2=1$

So it seems that $\sqrt{2(a+b)^2}\leq \sqrt{2}$ maybe it is $|iz-\overline{z}|\leq \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't quite make that conclusion work. We have that $(a + b)^2 = 1 + 2ab$, so you need to be able to control $ab$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just using the triangle inequality $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$, you have
$$ |iz-\overline{z}|\le|iz|+|\overline{z}|= 2.$$

Comment: Now my answer just feels silly....

Comment: @user296602, not really

Answer (score 4):

$z$, $\bar{z}$ and $iz$ all lie on the unit circle $|z|=1$.
The distance between any two points on the circle cannot exceed the length of the diameter. QED.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that seems (at least to me...) more geometrically natural: If $|z| = 1$, then

$$|iz - \overline{z}| = |z|\left|i - \frac{\overline{z}}{z}\right| = |i - \overline{z}^2|.$$

Now $\overline{z}^2$ is just some point in the unit circle, so call it $w$. Then all you need to justify is that

$$|w| = 1 \implies |i - w| \le 2$$

which is geometrically quite clear - the extreme point is $w = -i$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to proceed from your point is by using the inequality $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ $$0\le (a+b)^2=1+2ab\le1+a^2+b^2= 2$$ And thus your quantity ends up being in the interval $\left[\sqrt0,\sqrt4\,\right]$.